# My code works for printing "*"s but not my desired pattern

Tags: java

my code works for printing 3 by 3 star pattern. But when I want to replace it with my desired one, it doesn't work. And I included the output that I get as well as the output I want to get

```
  /*
    * * *
    * * *
    * * * /*

    /* The pattern I want to make is:
   +--+--+--+
   |  |  |  |
   +--+--+--+
   |  |  |  |
   +--+--+--+ 
   |  |  |  |
   +--+--+--+ */

The output that I get:
    *--*
|  |*--*
|  |*--*
|  |
*--*
|  |*--*
|  |*--*
|  |
*--*
|  |*--*
|  |*--*
|  |

 public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

for( int i = 0; i<=2; i++){
    for(int j =0; j<=2; j++){
    System.out.print("*--*\n|  |");
    }
  System.out.println();

}
  }
 }
```

Comment: How does it not work, what's the output?

Comment: SurvivalMachine I just included both my desired output and the output that I want in my code..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                System.out.print("*--");
            }
            System.out.println("*");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                System.out.print("|  ");
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("*--");
        }
        System.out.println("*");
    }
```

Your code doesn't work, because you took several characters (which are not even positioned next to each other in line) as one.

Comment: Omg ! u r genius.. That wouldn't even pass my little brain...I feel so dumb..Thank u ..u helped me alot..I'm gonna accept your answer in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use the code:
    package stack_holder;

```
public class Stack_Holder {

public static void main(String[] args) {


for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

        for(int l=0;l<4;l++){

            for(int j=0;j<1;j++){


                System.out.print("+");

            }

            for(int k=0;k<1;k++){

            if(l==3){break;}
                System.out.print("-");

            }


    }
        System.out.println("");

        for(int m=0;m<4;m++){

            if((i==3) ||(i==4)){break;}
            System.out.print("| ");

        }
        System.out.println("");


    }        
}

}
```

Comment: @Marie Mirbekian your's answer is here

Comment: Hi there.. Your code looks very interesting.. I love the way u did all that calculations..using nested loops is truly confusing.. But u helped me alot! I'm very thankful

Comment: If I could, I would choose both answers.. Because I love both.. I wish I had that option

Comment: Welcome @MarieMirbekian.You can accept my answer and upvote it.

Comment: My purpose in this site is to help others as i can @MarieMirbekian.

Comment: I truly appreciate for your help.. I hope u be here on my other questions..Nice to know u

Comment: thanks @MarieMirbekian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116404/discussion-between-stack-holder-and-marie-mirbekian).